# Using own Vector type in OpenCL seems to be faster

Tags: c++, c, opencl, gpgpu, vectorization

I saw an smallpt implementation in OpenCL and the author uses his own vector types and prepocessor macro functions in the kernel.

```
typedef struct { float x, y, z; } Vec;

#define vinit(v, a, b, c) { (v).x = a; (v).y = b; (v).z = c; }
#define vsmul(v, a, b) { float k = (a); vinit(v, k * (b).x, k * (b).y, k * (b).z) }
#define vdot(a, b) ((a).x * (b).x + (a).y * (b).y + (a).z * (b).z)
#define vnorm(v) { float l = 1.f / sqrt(vdot(v, v)); vsmul(v, l, v); }
and much more...
```

I tested the code and replaced the user-defined vector types and operations with the standard build-in float3 type. I was surprised that the original implementation of the author was 10 frames faster than the variant with built-in float3. After that I tested a little bit the situation with the Intel OpenCL Applications Kernel Builder and it seems to be confirmed that the built-in functions are slower.

Any ideas why? The vendors recommend the build-in vectory types :/

Comment: What language is this? There is no builtin type `float3` in C or C++.

Comment: What does your benchmark code look like? What hardware are you running this on?

Comment: This is OpenCL C based on C99 standard for GPGPU programming.

The benchmark code was simply to run some basic vector operations over a million times and compared this with the user-defined version. (norm, cross, dot, add, mull, ...)

Hardware for benchmark was Intel i7-3630QM (Intel HD 4000 didn't work in the kernel builder). And the smallpt code run on my nvidia quadro gpu (NVS 5200M)

And here is the original smallpt opencl implementation http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/benchmark-files/SmallptGPU-v1.6pts-1.tar.bz2

Comment: Is the code using these built-in types running on a CPU, or on a GPU?

Comment: Benchmark code was running on the i7-CPU, because of the bugs with the Intel HD GPU in the Intel's Kernel Builder. All other code was running on the nvidia quadro card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user defined vector is a true 3 element vector, using a size of 3 floats.
However, the OpenCL `float3` vector is really using a `float4` vector, as can be seen in `cl_platform.h`:

```
/* cl_float3 is identical in size, alignment and behavior to cl_float4. See section 6.1.5. */
typedef  cl_float4  cl_float3;
```

Originally using vectors was the recommended programing technique for OpenCL. Since the full SIMD arquitecture was exploited compared to the plain non-vector code.

But as the OpenCL compiler evolved, now the compiler is clever enough to internally vectorize the user code. **Sometimes (I have seen it with other kernels too, even with my own) it is better to write the code in plain elements and let the compiler re-vectorize it, rather that using the default vector types.** So, I recommend that unless vector eases the programming task and is easyer to read (for example 2D processings, etc..), don't use OpenCL vectors nowadays.

Probably the user defined `vector3` is using less registers, and less spill out. Or it could be that another vector arrangement is better for the algorithm, and the compiler is free to reshape the code in the user-defined vector case.

An indeep analysis of what is happening should have to be performed with the compiled PTX code.

Comment: NVIDIA hardware is not vector hardware, so the compiler scalar-izes all of the built-in vector types.

Furthermore, some compilers, such do that, and then re-vectorize your code so multiple work items form one execution path. In other words, if 4 work items fit in a SSE or AVX vector type then the vector code will run four work items at a time on one core. This is independent of your use of vector types in your code.

AMD's previous generation hardware was vectorized and used the OpenCL C vector types when it could. Their latest hardware is scalar.

Comment: @Dithermaster Yes, I read this in the AMD OpenCL Optimization Guide.

So all in all what do you think is the best solution to handle this problem running vector code on all platforms much fast as possible.

Comment: And thanks for your experience DarkZeros. The situation was a little bit confusing fore a OpenCL newbie

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little. For NVIDIA GPUs (I don't know about AMD), there are load instructions for 32 bits (LD.32), 64 bits (LD.64) and 128 bits (LD.128), but no 96-bit load. Loading a true float3 from DRAM is implemented as two separate instructions--one LD.32 and one LD.64. If you're loading consecutive float3's in consecutive threads in a warp as you should for a float2, double or float4, you're actually accessing data with a 96-bit stride in two separate instructions, resulting in replays. The same is true for store instructions. I would guess this is the reason for the choice to typedef them to float4.